# How to sync Outlook tasks and Google Tasks?

Tags: outlook, google-tasks

Is there anyway to sync between Google tasks and Outlook tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/google/), which is supposed to sync Outlook to Google, and vice versa.